# Почему python 2.7 просто так останавливается?

Tags: python-2.7

Всем привет. Я собираюсь написать дурака (карточная игра)
на python. Но у меня возникла ошибка. Программа просто останавливается, когда бот должен взять карты, которые не смог отбить. Программа просто пишет, то что не должна и перестаёт работать. Что делать?
Заранее спасибо
Код:

```
from cards import Card
import random
#ВСЕ ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ
#СПИСКИ
koloda = []
good_cards = []
myList = []
botList = []
players = [myList, botList]
desk = []
#Управление игрой
job = 0
the_ability = False
turn = True
game = True
#Козырь
trump = random.randint(1, 4)
if trump == 1:
    trumps = "Diamonds"
elif trump ==2:
    trumps = "Hearts"
elif trump == 3:
    trumps = "Spades"
else:
    trumps = "Clubs"
#СОЗДАНИЕ КОЛОДЫ
for suit_id in range(1,5):
    for rank_id in range(6, 15):
        new_card = Card(suit_id, rank_id, rank_id)
        if suit_id == trump:
            new_card.value = new_card.value + 50
        koloda.append(new_card)

#РАЗДАЧА КАРТ
for i in players:
    for k in range(0,6):
        a = random.choice(koloda)
        i.append(a)
        koloda.remove(a)
    
while game:

#Добираем карты
    if job == 4:
        while job == 4:
            if len(myList) != 6 or len(botList) != 6:
                if len(koloda) > 0:
                    for i in players:
                        if len(i) < 6:
                            a = random.choice(koloda)
                            i.append(a)
                            koloda.remove(a)
                else:
                    if len(myList) > 0 and len(botList) > 0:
                        job = 0
                    else:
                        game = False
            else:
                job = 0
#ВЫВОД ДАННЫХ НА ЭКРАН
for i in range(0, 5):
    print" "
print "Козырь:", trumps
print "Карт в колоде:", len(koloda)
print "Карт у противника:", len(botList)
if len(desk) > 0:
    last_card = desk[len(desk) - 1]
    print"Доска:"
    for i in desk:
        print i
        if desk.index(i) + 1 % 2 == 0:
            print " "
print " "
print"Моя колода:"
for i in players:
    for q in i:
        print i.index(q) + 1, q
    print" "

        
#Наш ход
    if turn:
#Бросаем карту
        if job == 0:
            num_card = (input("Введите номер карты: ")) - 1
            if num_card < len(myList):
                desk.append(myList[num_card])
                del myList[num_card]
                turn = False
                job = 1
            else:
                print" "
                print"у тебя нету такой карты"
                print " "
#Отбиваем карту
        elif job == 1:
            answer = input("Введите 1 если хотите побить карту или 0 если если хотите взять карты")
            if answer == 1:
                num_card = (input("Введите номер карты: ")) - 1
                if num_card < len(myList):
                    my_card = myList[num_card]
#Подбрасываем карту или говорим "Бито"
        elif job == 2:
            if (len(desk) < 12) and len(botList) > 0:
                answer = input("Введите 1 если хотите подбросить или 0 если ваши карты биты: ")
                if answer == 1:
                    num_card = (input("Введите номер карты: ")) - 1
                    if num_card < len(myList):
                        my_card = myList[num_card]
                        for i in desk:
                            if i.rank_id == my_card.rank_id:
                                the_ability = True
                        if the_ability:
                            desk.append(my_card)
                            myList.remove(my_card)
                            job = 1
                            turn = False
                            the_ability = False
                        else:
                            print"Ты не можешь подкинуть эту карту"
                    else:
                        print"Такой карты нет в твоей колоде"
                elif answer == 0:
                    desk = []
                    turn = False
                    job = 4
                else:
                    print'Я тебя не понял.'
            else:
                print "Доска переполнена"
                turn = False
                job = 4
#Подбрасываем карту или говорим "Пас"
        elif job == 3:
            answer = input("Введите 1 если хотите подбросить или 0 если блольше не хотите подкидывать карту: ")
#Ошибка здесь
            if answer == 0:
                for i in desk:
                    botList.append(i)
                    desk.remove(i)
                turn = False
                job = 4
            
            if answer == 1:
                num_card = (input("Введите номер карты: ")) - 1
                if num_card <= len(myList):
                    my_card = myList[num_card]
                    for i in desk:
                        if i.rank_id == my_card.rank_id:
                            the_ability = True
                    if the_ability:
                        desk.append(my_card)
                        myList.remove(my_card)
                    else:
                        print"Ты не можешь подкинуть эту карту"
                else:
                    print"Такой карты нет в твоей колоде"
            else:
                print'Я тебя не понял.'
            
#Ход противника
    if not turn:
#Отбиваем карту
        if job == 0:
            best_card = botList[0]
            for i in botList:
                if best_card.value > i.value:
                    best_card = i
            desk.append(best_card)
            botList.remove(best_card)
            turn = True
            job = 1
        elif job == 1:
            last_card = desk[len(desk) - 1]
            for i in botList:
                if (i.value > last_card.value and i.suit_id == last_card.suit_id) or (i.value > 50 and i.value > last_card.value):
                    good_cards.append(i)
                    botList.remove(i)
            if len(good_cards) > 0:
                best_card = good_cards[0]
                for i in good_cards:
                    if best_card.value > i.value:
                        best_card = i
                    desk.append(best_card)
                    good_cards.remove(best_card)
                    for i in good_cards:
                        botList.append(i)
                        good_cards.remove(i)
                    job = 2
                    turn = True
            else:
                job = 3
                turn = True
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не пишите новые программы на Python 2.7. Это устаревший язык, установите последнюю версию интерпретатора.

Comment: Ошибка будет если turn = True и job = 3. Если ввести answer = 0, то программа напишет "я тебя не понял", хотя не должна. А потом и вовсе перестанет что либо писать

Comment: То же самое на последней версии python

Answer (score 0):

Всё понял, всё работает, просто я написал невыполнимые условия